# Implementing Azure ADFS in Web Forms Application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, azure-active-directory, adfs

I have a traditional ASP.NET 3.5 Web Forms application. As of now it is using On-Premise ADFS which is working fine. Now we have a requirement to change on-premise ADFS to Azure ADFS.

In the web.config, I have changed the required URL to point to Azure ADFS but it is not working. I checked Stackoverflow and Googled around but I found examples related to ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core where changes are required in Startup.cs file.

I want to know what all changes are required in my traditional Web Forms application. Any example link would help.

Comment: What do you mean by Azure ADFS? Do you mean ADFS running in a VM hosted by Azure or Azure AD?

Comment: @rbrayb Azure AD

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it working by using the Azure AD parameters rather than the ADFS ones e.g. metadata. What protocol are you using?

There are some ADFS [samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/development/single-page-application-with-ad-fs). Look at the LHS under ADAL and MSAL. These generally start with an Azure AD sample and show how to convert to ADFS. So you can then work "backwards".

**Update**

I had a look at that code. It looks like OIDC? "Redirect_Uri" is not a WS-Fed parameter.

There is a WS-Fed sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-wsfederation/).

Comment: I am using WSFederation. I have one more post in SO, I have posted sample code there.